# Problema con etiquetas html en IONIC

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Estoy tratando de migrar una app ionic 3 a ionic 4
El problema es que al traer la carpeta components del proyecto v3 al proyecto v4los templates html de estos componentes dan error estilo:

```
'ion-header' is not a known element:

'ion-toolbar' is not a known element:
```

Comentando el import de Events en el archivo ts del componente, deja de mostrar el error en el html, pero esto traslada el error al ts

intete con estas soluciones, pero ninguna me funciono
https://gist.github.com/sagrawal31/76c089251008ac746fc8cf3aef4bc261
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/the-events-provider-is-deprecated-ionic-4/174160/10

Comment: Se necesita más información para encontrar la raíz del problema, pero seguramente lo que te falta es declarar o exportar en el módulo alguno de estos componentes que estás creando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error puede deberse por no declarar los componentes en el modulo principal.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
...
declarations: [MyComponent]
}
```

o también por no haber importado IonicModule en el modulo del componente,

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule
  ],
  declarations: [ExamplePage]
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, en mi caso olvide importar IonicModule